# How to remove linux mint at GRUB?

Tags: uninstall

I installed linux mint manually.

now i removed it but at the time of boot screen it is showing

```
"linux mint 12 flubox, 3.0.0-13-generic (/dev/sda5)"
"linux mint 12 flubox, 3.0.0-13-generic (/dev/sda5)-recovery mode"
```

And when i boot up it shows the login screen of linuxmint.
but login screen do't have option to login to linux mint it has option for only ubuntu it means the linuxmint is removed.

How i can get back my default ubuntu login screen and ubuntu boot up?

I think at the time of installation of linuxmint i allowed linux mint desktop environment and replaced ubuntu desktop enviroment.

Comment: Did you install bootloader in ubuntu ? I think a simple `sudo update-grub` would do the trick.

Comment: its not working

Comment: How did you removed Mint?, did you just deleted the partitions or what? what @sagarchalise says shouild fix it.

Comment: @paru38 try running `sudo os-prober && sudo update-grub` If you had run `os-prober` after installing Mint.

Comment: i just type sudo apt-get remove mint-meta-mate

Comment: Okay none of this advice helps.  os-prober finds other oses not linux.  also lsb_release is the correct version and I have upgraded Ubuntu, still seeing linux mint on every new kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you paru38.

Using ***sudo apt-get remove mint-meta-mate*** removed most of linux mint.

However, I then used ***sudo apt-get autoremove mint-meta-mate*** to completely remove linux mint.